# How to find the equivalence classes on a relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, equivalence-relations

Suppose we define the relation $∼$ by $v∼w$ (where $v$ and $w$ are arbitrary elements in $R^n$) if there exists a matrix $$A∈ GL_n(R)$$ such that $v=Aw$.  What are the equivalence classes for $∼$ in this case? NOTE:$GL_n(R)$ is a set that contains all the $n×n$ matrices with $det≠0$

Comment: @Yanko so basically all elements in $R_n$ ?

Comment: @Yanko Almost, but not quite…

Comment: You have one problem with the zero vector. Let me write a complete answer.

Comment: @M.Winter Are  you  sure? what about the inverse?

Comment: @JJW22 You are right. I forgot that we talk about invertible matrices. I will delete the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation works like that: The zero vector is only in relation with itself. All the other vectors are in relation with each other

Proof: if $v=0$ then $Av=0$ for every matrix and therefore $0\sim w$ if and only if $w=0$.

Now take $v\not = 0$ and $w\not = 0$. I claim that $v\sim w$, since $v\not = 0$ you can find $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$ such that $\mathcal{B}_v:=\{v,v_1,...,v_{n-1}\}$ a basis, similarly find $w_1,...,w_{n-1}$ such that $\mathcal{B}_w:=\{w,w_1,...,w_{n-1}\}$ is another basis.

Now define a matrix by the following linear map : $$A(\lambda v + \lambda_1 v_1 +...+\lambda_{n-1} v_{n-1} ) := \lambda w+\lambda w_1 +...+\lambda w_{n-1}$$

(i.e. $A$ is the unique linear transformation that sends one basis to another this is usually denoted as $[I]^{\mathcal{B}_v}_{\mathcal{B}_w}$)

In particular you find a matrix $A$ which is invertible (because it sends a basis to itself), hence $\det A \not = 0$ such that $Av=w$. It follows that $v\sim w$.

Comment: Can you make it more explicit? I still have problem seeing the equivalence classes on ~. Thank you!

Comment: @JJW22 yes. $v\sim 0$ if and only if $v=0$ and $v\sim w$ for any $v,w\not =0$.

Answer (score 0):

Given any unit vectors, there is a nonsingular rotation matrix that takes the first vector to the other. Given any non-zero, non-unit vector, there is some non-singular scaling matrix that takes the vector to a unit vector. So given two arbitrary non-zero vectors $v$ and $w$, there are $S_v$ and $S_w$ such that $S_vv$ and $S_ww$ are unit vectors, and $R$ such that $R(S_vv)=S_ww$. Then $w=(S_w^{-1}RS_v)v$. So taking $A=S_w^{-1}RS_v$, we have that $v=Aw$, so given any non-zero vectors $v$, $w$, $v$~$w$; the set of non-zero vectors is an equivalence class.

Comment: Sorry, I have problem seeing the connection between this and equivalence classes. Can you elaborate on it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There are two equivalence classes: $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$.